# Generating digital signature in php

Tags: php, ruby, digital-signature, sha256

I used to generate digital signature in Ruby like so:

```
def generate_signature
  data = "Databeingpassed"
  secret_key = "Somesecretkey" 
  digest = OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha256')
  Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, secret_key, data)).strip
end

Output: 2XBK7UXA9oDsfJj1TBE2maptpB6i1MJ4uadY1AXlQOQ=
```

How to achieve the same with Php, I'm using the following code in php, but the outputs are different

```
function generate_signature() {
  $data = "Databeingpassed"
  $secret_key = "Somesecretkey" 

  $message = hash('sha256', $secret_key, $data);
  return base64_encode($message);
}

Output: hgy/KMG3zTSgjUrzA/3nNvN+vApna6A7JqtZwx+r9Ng=
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way, in case if someone will need:

```
function generate_signature() {
  $data = "Databeingpassed"
  $secret_key = "Somesecretkey" 

  return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $secret_key, true));
}
```

The output:

```
2XBK7UXA9oDsfJj1TBE2maptpB6i1MJ4uadY1AXlQOQ=
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for your probleme

```html
 $("#btnSaveSign").click(function(e){
        html2canvas([document.getElementById('sign-pad')], {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var canvas_img_data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var img_data = canvas_img_data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
                //ajax call to save image inside folder
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'save_sign.php',
                    data: { img_data:img_data },
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

[jquery digital signature](https://techdevl.com/blog/p/digital-signature-generate-with-saving-as-image-using-html2canvat-ajax-php/)

Comment: This question is about creating an HMAC. How does that relate to your answer?